# Script to delete Shortcut on each user's desktop

Tags: scripting, batch-file, vbscript, windows-terminal-services

I'm looking for a script to remove a .lnk file that was placed on every user's desktop. I installed a program on a terminal server that put a .lnk file on every user's desktop, rather than putting one  shortcut in the "Public" desktop folder. I have since removed the program, but now I need a script to remove the shortcut from each user's desktop. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why a script?  if this is just 1 terminal server you should just be able to run:

```
forfiles /P c:\users /s /m shortcut.lnk /c "cmd /c del @path"
```

then add the shortcut back to the public desktop.

EDIT:  Well that will teach me to post a command that doesn't work... Seemed like it would though...  Anyway, I updated with a command that will work.  You may have to run from an administrative command prompt though.  NOTE (from comments on this answer):  this will also delete the shortcut.lnk file anywhere under the c:\users directory structure.  You can change the "del @path" to "dir @path" to make sure of the files before deleting them.

Comment: That will also remove any other files with the same name anywhere in the `C:\Users` hierarchy.  This may not be what he wants.

Comment: of course, but it may also be just fine for this purpose also :)  Low-tech solutions save a lot of time over bothering to write up some logic in a script if it isn't really necessary.

Comment: Yes, but you didn't *say* that this would delete every file with that name.  That's an important side effect.

Comment: I tried to run this command and it asked me if I wanted to also delete some unrelated files. It doesn't seem to be working..

Comment: I personally feel that this solution is a bit invasive for my tastes. The solution I offered works for only the shortcut you specify, so long as it is on the users desktop. Did my solution not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
for /D %%f in ("%1\*") do del "%%f\desktop\%2"
```

Save as a .bat and run something like this.

```
RemoveLnk.bat C:\Users Shortcut.lnk
```

This will go through C:\Users recursively and remove the specified shortcut from all users desktops.